# Is it rude to forward an email to someone left out of the email?

Tags: etiquette, email

I've emailed a professor/TA and cced my peers or also a different professor/TA and cced another professor/TA. However, sometimes I get emailed back only to my email, not the person cced, would it be rude to forward the email to the person cced?

I'm not sure in some cases I'm not sure why they would respond only to me when the question for example was relevant to all my group members, or as well, when I email a professor (A) a question on a project I'm working on with another professor (B) but professor A only replies to me instead of professor B cced.

I want to forward the email but I'm not sure what the person cced would think of my trustworthiness, especially considering she's my professor/supervisor.

Comment: Usually it is fine, but it depends on the content and personalities involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit subtle, since email client software is different for different people. A lot of people replying to an email don't take the time and effort to look at who (all) will get the mail.

In the general case, for a group that communicates frequently, you can, perhaps, establish guidelines. In the specific case, you could ask the professor that sent the email - i.e. A.

But, if the mail is about group work that everyone *should* see and has no personal elements, then there is little to fear. It was probably just an oversight.

Comment: I see, I don't believe there are personal elements though I'm unsure. The professor I emailed (A) said they're no longer that familiar on the topic due to personal reasons but that they'd ask their colleague on it. So I believe it should be okay forwarding it to the other professor (B) cced?

Comment: They will probably work it out themselves.

Comment: Yes, when in doubt assume user error. If the people involved wanted their answer to be confidential they would/should say so. In academia, people get zillions of emails; clearing inboxes is a chore. Many people will take as little time as they can over each email.